# AWS IoT Core Basic Ingest identify exceeded qoutas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, quota, aws-iot-core

I am currently working with IoT Core Basic Ingest and it looks like we're hitting some quotas of IoT. Weirdly enough it happened when we switched to the Basic Ingest model. We didn't have those issues working with the message broker/topic.
The logs show only that PublishIn fails with the reason "throttled" but that's not enough to identify the problem.
Could someone point me in the right direction to identify where the problem lies?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the AWS IoT Core quotas page to see the quotas and limits that may apply to your specific use case: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/iot-core.html#limits_iot

Comment: I know what quotas apply, but none of them seem to be my case. For example, there's a limit of 100 messages per second per clientId and that's why we have multiple clients, I checked MQTT metrics, and Throttled + Success seems to be around the limit, but it doesn't explain why 3k of 12k request got throttled. I can't find a quota that would fit here, that's why I need a way of find out which quota we exceed

Comment: I see. Without more details I‘m also unable to identify the issue. Sorry.

Comment: Hey Dennis, I can give you more details, what details you'd need to help?